# How to remove logo header/sidebar header from shinydashboardPlus?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

I am using shinydashboardPlus because I want to use `dashboardFooter`, but I removed the sidebar. the problem is that the logo header/sidebar header is still there, and haven't figure out a way to remove it. I tried to solve the issue by changing my css script, with no luck. The image shows what I want to remove:

[image: Original app]

Here is a simple, reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

header <- dashboardHeader(tags$li(class = "dropdown",
                                  sidebarMenu(
                                    id = "mysearch",
                                    menuItem(
                                      text = "Main",
                                      tabName = "main",
                                      icon = icon("home")
                                    )
                                  )))


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = "0px"
 )



body <- dashboardBody()



ui <- (dashboardPage(
  header = header,
  sidebar = sidebar,
  body,
  footer = dashboardFooter(
    left = tags$b(
      icon("envelope"),
      tags$a(href = "mailto:", "myemail@email.no"),
      icon("home"),
      tags$a(href = "https://somesite.no", "www.somesite.no/")
    ),
    
    right = ""
    
  )
))


server <- function(input, output, session) {}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `titleWidth=0`, as

```
header <- dashboardHeader(
  titleWidth=0,
  tags$li(class = "dropdown",...)
)
```